# Replace text in range of values and return it to another range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please help me to realise replace text in range of values and return it to another range.

I try to use this script now, but it only take values from A1:

```
 function replaceBat() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var AAA = ss.getRange("A1:A1000").getValue();
      var AAAString = AAA.toString()
        .replace("1","2")
        .replace("5","6")
//and more than 50 terms;
      var prov = ss.getRange("B1:B1000");
      prov.setValue(AAAString);
      }
```

In range A1:A1000 - values to change,

B1:B1000 - range to return changed values.

For example:
We have:

A1
12541

We need:

B1
22642

And so for all cells

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it because I got confused by "and more than 50 terms" . Do you mean you want to replace more than 50 characters ?

Comment: Ye, I see your answer and want to write about 50 criteria, but you make it first.Yes I mean I want to make more than 50 criteria, there will be characters and words and symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script. Of course you will have to change the arrays 'toBeChanged' and 'changeWith' according to your needs. Make sure the character that needs replacing and the character you want to replace it with, are in the same 'position' in their respective arrays.

```
function replaceBat() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    arr = [];
ss.getRange("A1:A1000")
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (value) {
        var changeWith = ["2", "6", "notest", "/"],
            toBeChanged = ["1", "5", "test", "@"] //add characters to be changed here, the characters you want to change these with in the same 'place' in the above array.
            .map(function (c, i) {
                return value = replaceAll(value.toString(), c, changeWith[i])
            })
            arr.push([value])
    });
ss.getRange("B1:B1000")
    .setValues(arr)
}

function replaceAll(v, c, r) {
return v.indexOf(c) > -1 ? v.replace(new RegExp(c, "g"), r) : v;
}
```

EDIT: if you want the values to be checked and replaced in one array (as requested in the comments) change the first script to:

```
function replaceBat2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    arr = [];
ss.getRange("A1:A1000")
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (value) {
        [["1", "2"], ["5", "6"], ["test", "notest"], ["a", "/"]]
            .map(function (c, i) {
                return value = replaceAll(value.toString(), c[0], c[1])
            })
        arr.push([value])
    });
ss.getRange("B1:B1000")
    .setValues(arr)
}
```

A (maybe faster ?) alternative to the second function (replaceAll) would be:

```
function replaceAll(v, c, r) {
return v.indexOf(c) > -1 ? v.split(c)
    .join(r) : v;
}
```

Comment: Nice work! Thank you! But is this posible to make every criteria in one row? Like: ["1","2"],["5","6"],["test","notest"],["/","@"] It would be very good!

Comment: Yeah! That what im looking for! Thank yu very much! And maybe you can advice what regular exprassions I can use here?

Comment: In case you use the second 'replaceAll' function you don't need regular expressions. If you want to use the first version a new regular expression is formed (for every first element in every row of the array [["1", "2"], ["5", "6"], ["test", "notest"], ["a", "/"]]. ). See: v.replace(new RegExp(c, "g"), r) "c" is that first element. "g" stands for global (replace everywhere) and "r" is the second element of the row (replacing value). Hope that helps ?

Comment: I mean if I want to replace every value which look like: M(any symbols)x to just Mx

Comment: If you just need the first and the last character you can try: input[0] + input.slice(-1) (given an inputvalue like M(anysymbols)x that would result in Mx